# How to understand "useBox" in react-three-fiber

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-three-fiber, cannon.js

I'm interested in learning how to create dynamic objects and group them together entirely in react/JavaScript.  I'm looking at the chair and table in this example as my model:

https://codesandbox.io/s/ragdoll-physics-forked-bntr9

At this point, I'm not as concerned about the "physics" but just how to create the three object such as a table that consist of 5 3D-Rectangles.

I downloaded the above example, and this is the code for the table:

```
function Table() {
  const [seat] = useBox(() => ({ type: 'Static', position: [9, -0.8, 0], args: [2.5, 0.25, 2.5] }))
  const [leg1] = useBox(() => ({ type: 'Static', position: [7.2, -3, 1.8], args: [0.25, 2, 0.25] }))
  const [leg2] = useBox(() => ({ type: 'Static', position: [10.8, -3, 1.8], args: [0.25, 2, 0.25] }))
  const [leg3] = useBox(() => ({ type: 'Static', position: [7.2, -3, -1.8], args: [0.25, 2, 0.25] }))
  const [leg4] = useBox(() => ({ type: 'Static', position: [10.8, -3, -1.8], args: [0.25, 2, 0.25] }))
  return (
    <>
      <Box scale={[5, 0.5, 5]} ref={seat} />
      <Box scale={[0.5, 4, 0.5]} ref={leg1} />
      <Box scale={[0.5, 4, 0.5]} ref={leg2} />
      <Box scale={[0.5, 4, 0.5]} ref={leg3} />
      <Box scale={[0.5, 4, 0.5]} ref={leg4} />
      <Suspense fallback={null}>
        <Mug />
      </Suspense>
    </>
  )
}
```

And at the top of the program I see this:

```
import {
  Physics,
  useBox,
  useCompoundBody,
  useCylinder,
  useSphere,
  usePlane,
  useConeTwistConstraint,
  usePointToPointConstraint
} from '@react-three/cannon'
```

Googling react-three/cannon took me to https://opensourcelibs.com/lib/use-cannon, and the "github" link took me to https://github.com/pmndrs/use-cannon, which I downloaded.

Is there a document to the "useBox", or do I have just have to read code to figure out how it works?

Without some doc, I can only do controlled variations, for example, suppose I just want to make the table legs longer, or the table top bigger?   I don't understand what joins the legs to the table, but I figure it must be the position or args:

I tried changing 1.8 to 2.8 as follows:
from

```
const [leg1] = useBox(() => ({ type: 'Static', position: [7.2, -3, 1.8], args: [0.25, 2, 0.25] }))
```

to

```
const [leg1] = useBox(() => ({ type: 'Static', position: [7.2, -3, 2.8], args: [0.25, 2, 0.25] }))
```

and I could see the leg come out from the table top.

I knew all table legs had equal length, so I tried changing some number that was the same for all four legs (then later noticed two had 1.l8 and two had -1.8).
I'm also guessing that some set of three parameters must be length, width, height.

Then I tried changing:

> ```
>   <Box scale={[0.5, 4, 0.5]} ref={leg1} />
>   <Box scale={[0.5, 4, 0.5]} ref={leg2} />
> ```

to

> ```
>   <Box scale={[0.5, 6, 0.5]} ref={leg1} />
>   <Box scale={[0.5, 6, 0.5]} ref={leg2} />
> ```

And that deed indeed length two legs, but up through the top of the table.

**So bottom line question is not how to do change the length of the legs, but how to find the documentation.**

I searched the pmndrs library for "useBox", and see a many many matches:
[image]

I looked at the sources\hooks.ts and found this, which doesn't help me at all:

```
export function useBox(fn: GetByIndex<BoxProps>, fwdRef: Ref<Object3D> = null, deps?: DependencyList) {
  const defaultBoxArgs: Triplet = [1, 1, 1]
  return useBody('Box', fn, (args = defaultBoxArgs): Triplet => args, fwdRef, deps)
}
```

Comment: https://schteppe.github.io/cannon.js/docs/classes/Box.html

Comment: @iLuvLogix <Box has a parm called scale.  I don't see that on the page above.  And what is the relationship between useBox and Box?

Comment: `useBox` is the hook on one of the possible implementations of a Box-class as far as I understand it, since react-three-fibre relies on cannon as stated here: `import {useBox} from '@react-three/cannon'`. `scale` can be used on the returned `mesh` via `scale={foo ? 2 : 1}` for example

Answer (score 2):

> At this point, I'm not as concerned about the "physics" but just how
> to create the three object such as a table that consist of 5
> 3D-Rectangles.

useBox is physics-only, it comes from the physics library "cannon", not from threejs or r3f. it approximates a shape and links it to arbitrary geometry. the physics engine now manages a literal box, a cube, and subjects it to gravity and other colliders. if your shape resembles something like a sphere you'd use useSphere instead and so on.

the example you have picked to learn either threejs or r3f is a hard one, i would not start with physics. the example on the github main page (https://codesandbox.io/s/rrppl0y8l4?file=/src/App.js) covers some basics, combine this with threejs docs at hand and you will have a much more comfortable learning experience.

a box in threejs (in react notation) is no more than this:

```
<mesh position={[1, 2, 3]} rotation={[Math.PI / 3, 0, 0]}>
  <boxGeometry />
  <meshBasicMaterial color="red" />
</mesh>
```

and you form groups like so:

```
<group>
  <mesh>
    ..
```

if you want to start with physics later, here are some easier ones:

- falling cubes: https://codesandbox.io/s/simple-physics-demo-z8e6m
- christmas baubles: https://codesandbox.io/s/bestservedbold-christmas-baubles-zxpv7
- arkanoid: https://codesandbox.io/s/arkanoid-under-60-loc-66cd7

Comment: The reason I picked that example is that it showed a table and a chair, which showed how to 'glue' a bunch of 3D rectangles (boxes) together to form a more real world object (without using a .glb file).  The only other one I found is this one, which had some fences: https://codesandbox.io/s/threejs-journey-ni6v4?file=/src/components/Model.js, but they might be from a .jpg or .glb. 

I'm doing some research to see if we could build an interactive shed designer, where we  can change the size of the shed dynamically.  If we used a .glb file, then I believe we would need one for each size.

Comment: Turns out the fences in the second example are from a .glb file as well.

Comment: Well usebox has properties I'm sure, but essentially no documentation

Comment: @Paul nice Arkanoid example. I'm coming into mood to create a complete Arkanoid revival with the R3F library :)